# How to delete temporary files in scons build without causing them to be rebuilt

Tags: scons

In the build I'm trying to do, there're 2 steps to generate the output

a.bin -> a.c   (convert any file into a C file with an array storing the contents)
a.c -> a.o

a.c could be massive and should be deleted after a.o is generated.

Here's what I tried so far

1. Use separate builders for each step. For the last step, use target.AddPostAction(Delete("a.c"))

This does delete the temp file, but when you build again, a.c gets regenerated because SCons builds all targets by default unlike make

Is there some command to tell SCons to not build a target unless it's needed by another target? It would be the opposite of AlwaysBuild()

2. Create a custom builder that does both steps (target=a.o, source=a.json), so that SCons doesn't even know about a.c.

This required me to generate my own command for compiling C, which works for GCC, but not the Microsoft compiler. Is there any way to get the SCons generated C compile command or have SCons execute that command immediately?

Comment: Your approach will always be difficult to manage and express in *SCons*. It is designed as a file-centered build system based on the idea of detecting content changes. So it will always need the contents of `a.c` being present, such that it can decide whether `a.o` is up-to-date or needs to get rebuilt. There may be tweaks to get around it partially, but your current mindset doesn't really fit the approach that SCons takes. Just sayin'... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
Ignore('a.o','a.c')
```

## haven't tried, but it might work.